# Android API вне Java

Tags: android, api

Возможно ли взаимодействовать с Android в обход Java?
Например, сделать бинарник, который будет, например, менять громкость? Включать Wi-Fi? И подобное...

Comment: Поскольку непосредственно с устройствами (audio, wi-fi и т.д.) работает ядро (linux), то используя те же интерфейсы с ним, что использует Java, вы можете проделать то же самое и без нее (только как при этом будут функционировать все компоненты Android, это большой вопрос)